# Gaussian primes in translations of lattices in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am considering undertaking some independent research in my summer break studying Gaussian primes in translations of lattices in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, i.e. sets of the form $ \{ a+sx+tw:s,t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ where $a,x,w \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. I would most likely ask myself questions such as when does this set contain infinitely many Gaussian primes (if ever), extending the method of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

If anybody knows any results relating to Gaussian primes in translations of lattices in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ please let me know!

Comment: If your lattice is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the analogue of Dirichlet's theorem is known, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29190/dirichlets-theorem-for-number-fields

Comment: I believe such questions can be answered by studying the methods introduced by Fouvry and Iwaniec in this paper: Gaussian Primes (https://eudml.org/doc/206979). See also my paper with Peter Lam and Damaris Schindler, which generalizes Fouvry-Iwaniec to arbitrary positive definite binary quadratic forms satisfying basic hypotheses: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1112/jlms.12336